# BufferedWriter writing to console instead of text file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

These are the contents of the constructor of a class which is called by the main method.

```
    File f = null;
    Scanner s;
    try {
        f = new File(getClass().getResource("/LOL.txt").toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        s = new Scanner(f);
        while(s.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(s.nextLine());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile(), false);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write("LOL");
    bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output in the console:

```
LOL
```

The contents of the file remain unchanged even after repeated runs. My IDE is eclipse

Comment: Print f.getAbsoluteFile().toString() and see what that gives you.

Comment: Damn, this code is full of potential bugs. Should I correct them?

Comment: Please correct them

Answer (score 1):

You parametrize your `FileWriter` with `boolean append` set as `false`.

Therefore, the same file will be written over every time that given constructor is executed, and `"LOL"` will be printed in it.

Before printing `"LOL"`, a `Scanner` reads each line and prints it, hence the `LOL` printed in our system out.

Also note, you probably want to declare your `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter` out of the `try` block, so you can flush and close them in a `finally` block.

Comment: I removed the scanner part. It does not print to the console but does not even write to the file. No exceptions

Comment: @ARJAVGARG how are you testing that the file isn't written on?

Comment: I close it in eclipse (before running) and open it in the windows explorer

Comment: @ARJAVGARG and your file doesn't contain `LOL`?

Comment: if I print f.getAbsoluteFile().toString() it gives me the correct path

Answer (score 0):

This post only contains the initial question, as-is with everything corrected to avoid several resource-related bugs. It assumes Java 6 or lower.

I shouldn't get any upvote so please don't ;)

```
package so39452286;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().run();
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/LOL.txt").toURI());
      Scanner scanner = null;
      try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
          System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
      } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
          scanner.close();
        }
      }
      Writer writer = null; // Holds the main resource, not the wrapping ones.
      try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), false);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        bw.write("LOL");
        bw.flush(); // You forgot to flush. Ok, close() does it, but it's always better to be explicit about it.
      } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
          writer.close();
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Do something with e.
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Printing LOLLOL to the console

Comment: I just copied/pasted the whole code that I used. All I ever get to my console are 1. an empty text the first time I run because `LOL.txt` doesn't contain anything and 2. The text `LOL`.